# Cannot remove broken account from "Accounts used by other apps" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

There is a broken "Work or school account" in my Windows 10 "E-mail & accounts" settings. On every startup, my computer shows a notification saying

> The account is broken and must be repaired. The password was possibly changed.

I would like to completely remove that account from my system. However, it does not have a <kbd>Remove</kbd> button, just a <kbd>Manage</kbd> button, which takes me to a https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com website (from my employer) which shows my mobile device, but not my desktop computer as registered devices. How do I remove this account from my computer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many guides online just missed the spot to disconnect it. They all show it under the Email & Accounts only.

From the Settings, rather than using "Email & Accounts" go down by two to "Access work or school." On that screen, you should get a list of the same accounts, but Disconnect is the only option if you click on an account for more details.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: I have nothing under "Access work or school" but an unremovable account in the Email & Accounts page.  Any ideas?

Comment: I believe the account came from office 365, which I have uninstalled to no avail

Answer (score 0):

## How to disconnect from a broken professionnal or school account on Windows 10

Here are screenshots for [Ray's excellent answer](https://superuser.com/a/1538276/280)
[image: Wrong step, it's not 'Manage' in 'E-mails and accounts']

[image: Select 'Access work or school']

[image: Select 'Disconnect' for the account you want to get rid off]